# How to create a Flexible RadialAxisPlot with Manipulate using Dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, dataset

I have the following code:

```
ClearAll[avail, access, util, stab, data, rlist, dlist];

avail = {3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6};
access = {2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3};
util = {1, 0, 7, 1, 0, 7};
stab = {6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2};

data = {avail, access, util, stab};
rlist = {"Andijan", "Bukhara", "Fergana", "Navoi", "Samarkand", 
   "Tashkent"};
dlist = {"Availability", "Access", "Utilization", "Stability"};

assocData = Dataset[AssociationThread[rlist, #] & /@ data];

Manipulate[
 RadialAxisPlot[
  assocData[#, All] & /@ Range[Length[FNSdim]] // Normal,
  GridLines -> "Polygon",
  PlotRange -> {0, 8},
  PlotLegends -> dlist,
  AxesLabel -> rlist,
  Filling -> False,
  ImageSize -> 400
  ],
 {{FNSdim, dlist[[{1}]], "dimensions"}, 
  Thread[Range[Length[dlist]] -> dlist], TogglerBar}
 ]
```

I have a set of variables given as `data`. This is a dataset with 6 regions across 4 dimensions at a given time. I have a trouble in `ToggleBar` which does not work as I expect.

I like to have a `Manipulate` with flexibility to choose from `dlist` and `rlist` at will. I may choose 3 regions across 2 dimensions, for example. Later on, I also want to add a time dimension by extending the set of variables as such:

```
avail = {{3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 6}};
access = {{2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}};
util = {{1, 0, 7, 1, 0, 7}, {2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3}};
stab = {{6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2}};
```

First sublist of a list such as `avail` is associated with `time 1` and second sublist of the same list associated with `time 2`.

Eventually, `Manipulate` should have three controls: one for time `list`, one for `list`, and one for `dlist`.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

avail = {3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6};
access = {2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3};
util = {1, 0, 7, 1, 0, 7};
stab = {6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2};

data = {avail, access, util, stab};
rlist = {"Andijan", "Bukhara", "Fergana",
   "Navoi", "Samarkand", "Tashkent"};
dlist = {"Availability", "Access", "Utilization", "Stability"};

assocData = Dataset[AssociationThread[rlist, #] & /@ data];

Manipulate[
 RadialAxisPlot[
  assocData[FNSdim, All] // Normal,
  GridLines -> "Polygon",
  PlotRange -> {0, 8},
  PlotLegends -> dlist[[FNSdim]],
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@
      Range[Length[dlist]])[[FNSdim]],
  AxesLabel -> rlist,
  Filling -> False,
  ImageSize -> 400],
 {{FNSdim, {1}, "dimensions"},
  Thread[Range[Length[dlist]] -> dlist],
  TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this Code. I added `{{FNSdim, {1}, "dimensions"}, Thread[Range[Length[dlist]] -> dlist], 
  TogglerBar, TrackingFunction -> (FNSdim = Sort[#]; &)}
 ]` to sort the labels even if they are randomly selected. Also, would it be easy to flip the diagram by interchanging `dimensions` with the `regions` as `PlotLegends`? This would allow a comparison of regions across dimensions.

Comment: I did find the solution to my question above. Just ignore my comments and questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (revised from @Bob's code above) answers to my second question:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

avail = {3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6};
access = {2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3};
util = {1, 0, 7, 1, 0, 7};
stab = {6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2};

data = {avail, access, util, stab};
rlist = {"Andijan", "Bukhara", "Fergana", "Navoi", "Samarkand", 
   "Tashkent"};
dlist = {"Availability", "Access", "Utilization", "Stability"};

assocData1 = Dataset[AssociationThread[dlist, #] & /@ Transpose@data];

Manipulate[
 RadialAxisPlot[
  assocData1[FNSdim, All] // Normal,
  GridLines -> "Polygon",
  PlotRange -> {0, 8},
  PlotLegends -> rlist[[FNSdim]],
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length[rlist]])[[FNSdim]],
  AxesLabel -> dlist,
  Filling -> True,
  ImageSize -> 400
  ],
 {{FNSdim, {1}, "regions"}, Thread[Range[Length[rlist]] -> rlist], 
  TogglerBar, TrackingFunction -> (FNSdim = Sort[#]; &)}
 ]
```

[image]

My third question, which is to add time dimension is still unanswered. Basically, there needs to be a control called `time` for `t=1 and t=2` to be placed above `regions` in order to compare regions over time.

Ideally, all these three controls should be combined to have a single figure allowing a comparison across `time`, `regions`, and `dimensions`.